# swift: Which filter should I choose, if I want to normalize image?

Tags: swift, filter, core-image, normalize

Like the topic, I'm using swift to predict model, and someone suggest me to use CoreImage to subtract mean value of input image, but it's seems I can't  do this with only one filter.  So which filter should I choose, if I want to normalize a image?

So far, I've tried to do this without CoreImage

```
let oriimage = self.convert(cmage: ciimage)
let uimean:UIImage = UIImage(color: oriimage.averageColor(), size: CGSize(width: oriimage.size.width, height:  oriimage.size.width))!
let cimean:CIImage = CIImage(image:uimean)!

ciimage.composited(over: cimean)
let image = self.convert(cmage: ciimage)
```

However, it's more like combine two images together but subtract.

Comment: Add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I look around CoreImage framework filter, I find that CIColorMatrix can work.

```
extension UIImage {
    func colorized(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        guard
            let ciimage = CIImage(image: self),
            let colorMatrix = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")
            else { return nil }
        var r: CGFloat = 1, g: CGFloat = 1, b: CGFloat = 1, a: CGFloat = 1
        color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        colorMatrix.setDefaults()
        colorMatrix.setValue(ciimage, forKey: "inputImage")
        colorMatrix.setValue(CIVector(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
        colorMatrix.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
        colorMatrix.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
        colorMatrix.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
        colorMatrix.setValue(CIVector(x: -r, y: -g, z: -b, w: 0), forKey: "inputBiasVector")
        if let ciimage = colorMatrix.outputImage {
            return UIImage(ciImage: ciimage)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let image = oriimage.colorized(with: color) ?? oriimage
let screensize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)
var face = image.cropped(boundingBox: facerect)
var left = image.cropped(boundingBox: leftrect)
var right = image.cropped(boundingBox: rightrect)


let col = 64,row = 64,c=3
face = face.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width:col,height:row))
```

However, the other problem is coming on the last line.  The result return nil and stop the application, but when I display the image, the image is good.